# Почему появляется ошибка 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, nginx, apache

Установил сервер nginx на ubuntu 20.04.
Задачей является, чтобы все, что отправляется к localhost/tonnel/ передавалось в файл index.php, который находится по путь /var/www/tonnel/index.php

Так же если запрос отправляется на localhost/ - то всё перенаправляется на localhost:8080

Со вторым проблем нет. Всё перенаправляется. Однако при этом с 1м возникает проблема.

Вылетает ошибка 403. При этом на папке tonnel и всём её содержимым доступ 777.

**Настройки nginx**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /tonnel {
        alias /var/www/tonnel; #Используем alias для указания пути к файлам
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

**Скриншот прав к папке**

[image: Права доступа]

**Код index.php**

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "Tonnel");
$connection = $mysqli->connect("localhost", "root", "root", "Tonnel");

if ($connection) {
    print("Wow");
}
else {
    print("bad");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дома попробовал сделать тоже самое. На удивление дома всё получилось.
На этот раз делал всё по советам со статьи.
Мою настройку почти не надо было менять. Нужно было лишь добавить **index** и **root**.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_domain.com;
    root /var/www;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.10.33:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /tonnel {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /tonnel/index.php$is_args$args;
   }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
```

[image: Скриншот того, что ошибки более нет]

После этого ошибка пропала.

Answer (score 0):

Так, ну проблем может быть много, вот примерные решения.
Убедись, что пользователь и группа Nginx (обычно это www-data) имеют право на чтение каталога /var/www/tonnel и всех его подкаталогов и файлов. Использование 777 является плохой практикой с точки зрения безопасности.

Использование alias вместо root в блоке location может иногда вызвать проблемы. Конфигурация с использованием root будет примерно следующей:

```
   location /tonnel {
       root /var/www;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /tonnel/index.php$is_args$args;
   }
```

Настрой location блок для файлов PHP, чтобы он включал /tonnel. Если это не будет сделано, nginx не сможет обрабатывать PHP файлы в каталоге /tonnel.

```
   location ~ /tonnel/.+\.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
   }
```

Чтобы точно выяснить причину ошибки 403, проверь журналы ошибок nginx, которые обычно находятся в /var/log/nginx/error.log. Они могут дать более конкретные подсказки о том, что именно вызывает проблему. Ну или если ты на laravel, то проверь laravel.log

Попробуй перезапустить nginx

sudo systemctl restart nginx

Я не очень понимаю почему, но почему-то мне не нравитс твой conf для nginx.

Вот моя конфа для проекта на laravel.
Заметь, что я index.php описываю не так как делаешь ты, у меня он лежит в public директории.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

Comment: вы были почти правы. Спасибо большое за пример вашей настройки. Мне помогло добавление index index.php. Без него выдается ошибка 403.